# Numba freevars using @autojit

Tags: python, numba, autojit

I am using numba @autojit decorator. 
What does the following error mean?

```
ByteCodeSupportError: does not support freevars
```

What are freevars?

Comment: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.6/doc/modules/closure.html the docs here have a comment about freevars. That's all i could find.

Comment: From what I can work out. The error was because I had defined the innerloop function (within a broader function which is bad for closure). Moving the innerloop() out of the main function fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "freevars" are variable references inside the function which refer to variables defined in an enclosing function.  The ability to handle closures disappeared in the major Numba refactor last year, but has been readded to the devel branch of Numba on Github and will appear in the next release.